# Selenium Webdriver/Java: handling calendar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to handle a website calendar.

When I run the code displayed below, it returns `"date did not match"` (`else` branch). When I use the `contains` function instead of `equalsignorecase`, it is selecting `12`th date instead of `31`.

The website which I'm trying to automatically test is **https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi/boa-village-civil-lines-north-delhi-21335**. Can anyone help?

---

```
public void logged_in_user_booking() throws InterruptedException
{
    calender.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    List<WebElement> dates= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".days"));

    System.out.println(dates);
    for(int i=0; i<dates.size(); i++)
    {
        datee = dates.get(i).getText();
        if(datee.equalsIgnoreCase("31"))
        {

            dates.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("date did not match");
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the outcome to be? Your current selector returns only 1 `WebElement`. What you're looking for is `List<WebElement> dates= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.days li"));`. Also the following steps also present some issues. Btw, your logic also has to change: what are you going to do if your month has `!= 31` days? :)

Comment: Thankyou very much it works now . In case !=31 i will select 30 else 28(feb). @iamdanchiv . I have just started with selenium i'm just practicing for now

Comment: Glad it worked SUMIT! Yes, you could try a `switch` statement to treat your exceptions. But, ultimately, your just trying to click on the last day of the month right? There are better ways to achieve this. Cheers!

Comment: @iamdanchiv : ya i read it now . Thanks for your help brother :). I have closed the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we agreed that the **EASY/QUICK FIX** was to get the entire list of `<li>` date `WebElement`s (e.g.: days): `List<WebElement> dates= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.days li"));`.

Yet, this is not the best solution to your problem. Learning Selenium is a enjoyable experience, especially if done properly. Most of the challenge comes from understanding **why**, **how** and **when** to choose a specific type of selector.

> **Problem:** Select the last date from the calendar widget.
>
> **Your solution:** Looping through the days `WebElements` of calendar and looking for the one which contains the last day (e.g: `31`).
>
> **Optimal solution:** Using an **[xpath-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)** which is better suited for this scenario as it removes the need to iterate through your entire list of monthly days.
>
> Thus, our **xpath-selector** should be: `//ul[contains(@class, "days")]/li/span[text() = 31]`. See bellow a **step-by-step breakdown** of how I came to that result using the browser console:

[image]

**Your code now should look like this:**

```
public void logged_in_user_booking() throws InterruptedException
{
    calender.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    List<WebElement> lastDay= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, "days")]/li/span[text() = 31]"));

    lastDay.click();
}
```

Looks better, right?! :)

**Next steps:** Now that you know how to target a specific element based on text using xpath, you can fine-tune your program to check for the exceptions: `28`,`30`, etc.

Hope it helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning Selenium, I would suggest a few things:

1. When you write code that will likely be reused, write a function. Picking a day on a site like this is something that you will likely use over and over. Think about what actions are likely to be repeated on the page and write functions for each. In this simple case, I would take in a day as a `String` and click the corresponding day.

   ```
   public static void setDay(String day)
   {
       driver.findElement(By.id("calendar")).click();
       By dayLocator = By.xpath("//ul[@class='days']/li/span[.='" + day + "']");
       new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dayLocator)).click();
   }
   ```

   Call it like

   ```
   driver.get("https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi/boa-village-civil-lines-north-delhi-21335");
   setDay("31");
   ```
2. Don't use `Thread.Sleep()`. I won't go into all the details since you will find plenty of reasons by doing some googling but it's a bad practice. Use an explicit wait, `WebDriverWait`, instead. Look in `ExpectedConditions` and see all the different built-in things you can wait for and use it whenever needed. Sometimes you will have to be clever on what you wait for but there's almost always something.
3. Learn CSS selectors and XPath. They are both very powerful... but prefer CSS selectors because they are faster and better supported. XPath is good primarily for finding an element based on contained text since CSS selectors cannot.

   [CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

   [CSS Selectors tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

   [Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

For bonus points... rewrite the function to:

1. take a `Date` parameter
2. pull out the day, month, and year
3. and select the correct date

It should be able to select a month from a different year/month.